# AngularJS without SPA and using ASP.NET MVC routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I want to use AngularJS non-SPA for my website along with ASP.NET MVC. The authentication happens through Active Directory so I find it best to use ASP.NET MVC for routing and authentication/authorization.

So what I would like to do is to create a _Layout.cshtml page that contains a `ng-app` definition, then each view derived from _Layout.cshtml would contain a `ng-controller` definition.

For RESTful data handling I would use a ASP.NET Web API.

The only problem I can think of are the URL query string parameters. If I would like to view some record specific by `ID`, I would always have to put the `ID` in a `ViewBag` in the ASP.NET MVC controller and obtain it in the view like this:

```
<script>
    var roomID = @ViewBag.roomID
</script>
```

Is there some better way to do this? Please shed some light. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**

Since you are not using Angularjs routing, you can use `ngInit`. It will initialize a new variable in your controller's scope and you will be able to access it like:

HTML (inside your controller):

```
<AnyElement ng-init="roomID = @ViewBag.roomID"></AnyElement>
```

JavaScript:

```
var roomID = $scope.roomID;
```

For more explanations see [ngInit documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit).

**Original Answer:**

In Angularjs you can access the query string parameter very easily like:

```
var paramValue = $routeParams.yourParameterName;
```

Or if you want to initialize a JavaScript variable then consider using `ngInit`. It will initialize a new variable in your controller's scope and you will be able to access it like:

HTML (inside your controller):

```
<AnyElement ng-init="roomID = @ViewBag.roomID"></AnyElement>
```

JavaScript:

```
var roomID = $scope.roomID;
```

For more explanations see [ngInit documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I can't access $routeParams unless I'm using AngularJS built-in routing system, which I'm not. I'm using ASP.NET MVC routing system, so I think I have to go with your second suggestion. :)

Comment: You are right, I should have read your question more carefully. I am just editing the answer now :). Hope you select it as answer if it helps.